How can I set a path to a variable in the bash shell?
I'm following the documentation for Seismic Unix software to install it on Ubuntu 22.04. However, I'm having trouble properly setting the path to a specific variable in the bash shell.
According to the documentation, the first step is to create a folder for installing the software, with I did on the path "/home/felipe/Work/Seismic_Unix_Hub". Then, I placed the file cwp_su_all_44R28.tgz in this folder and executed the command "tar -xvf cwp_su_all_44R28.tgz", which created a directory tree with "src" inside the mentioned folder.
The next step was to navigate to "/home/felipe" in the terminal to edit/create the files .bashrc and .bash_profile. The first file already exists, so I appended the following to the end of it:
# set the CWPROOT variable

export CWPROOT=/home/felipe/Work/Seismic_Unix_Hub

# set the PATH variable

export PATH=$PATH:$CWPROOT/bin:.

I created the second file and pasted the same content into it. Following the tip from "F. Hauri - Give Up GitHub" I removed the "$" from export CWPROOT.
Now, when I entered ". .bashrc" in the terminal no errors appears. If I entered "echo $PATH" now I receive the following:
"/home/felipe/miniconda3/bin:/home/felipe/miniconda3/condabin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/snap/bin:/bin:.:/bin:.:/bin:.:/bin:.:/bin:.:/bin:.:/bin:.:CWPROOT/bin:.:CWPROOT/bin:.:/home/felipe/Work/Seismic_Unix_Hub/bin:."
It apears that CWPROOT path is set, but typing "make install" I received the error "CWPROOT environment variable is not set!!".
Here is the link to the official documentation that I'm following:text.
I checked previous questions to avoid duplicating content, and it seems that none of them address the same issue I'm facing, at least from my beginner understanding of shell.
I appreciate all the help. Thanks in advance.

Don't prepend you variable name by a $ in export CWPROOT=/home/felipe/Work/Seismic_Unix_Hub command !

Hi, I did that right now. So the files includes:
export CWPROOT=/home/felipe/Work/Seismic_Unix_Hub
set the PATH variable
export PATH=$PATH:$CWPROOT/bin:.
After typing "echo $PATH" the path appears at the end of the output:
/home/felipe/miniconda3/bin:/home/felipe/miniconda3/condabin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/snap/bin:/bin:.:/bin:.:/bin:.:/bin:.:/bin:.:/bin:.:/bin:.:CWPROOT/bin:.:CWPROOT/bin:.:/home/felipe/Work/Seismic_Unix_Hub/bin:.
But "make install" returns CWPROOT environment variable is not set!!

Apologies if this is a "did you turn it off and back on again" suggestion: Likely you'll want to back out and re-enter your shell to pick up the new config. You can also source the files without having to back out so those environment variables are picked up immediately like source ~/.bashrc or source ~/.bash_profile. Essentially your current shell doesn't know about those new environment variables since it only runs .bashrc or .bash_profile once when it starts up.

You can see whether your environment variable is set, by doing a printenv CWPROOT. If it is not set, first test it by setting it manually. If this works, do the changes in your shell startup file, create a new shell and test again. Make sure that the new shell is one which actually processes your respective startup file. The bash man page tells you which file is processed depending on the kind of the shell.

BTW, are you really sure that you want to put your . into your PATH? In general, the PATH variable should only contain absolute pathes.

Hello all, thanks for the help. I managed how to solve the problem following the tip to set it manually from user1934428.
